# I used html2Canvas to convert web pages into pdf，because there was a lot of content in web pages

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I used html2Canvas to convert web pages into pdf, because there was a lot of content in web pages (pictures and charts), the exported pictures reached 13.4MB, set scale to 1, which could be exported normally, but it was too fuzzy to use, set scale to 2, some contents could not be exported. html2Canvas is there a file size setting? What should I do?

html2canvas 1.4.1

I tried to set scale to 1, and the export can be normal. Set scale to 2, the export is incomplete

Comment: You'd be better if you either leave the user to leverage their browser's built-in capability for printing to PDF - or you should generate the PDF on the server, e.g. with [Puppeteer](https://github.com/alvarcarto/url-to-pdf-api) or [PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com/). You will get **muuuuch** better results than with `html2canvas`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, because using the browser's built-in print function will truncate the image, which is not good. Because some images need to be generated on the front end, it is better to use the front end to generate reports. Now I find that the document is too big. 13.4MB, html2Canvas cannot convert such a big document. Now I plan to separate the web page into the upper and lower parts and export them separately, and then synthesize them into a pdf.

Comment: I don't know your particular usecase but if you limit the image size with CSS - the browser will not truncate it. You can also set bigger page dimensions (preferably in pixels) in your `@page` CSS rule - this will make a PDF with higher DPI. And even if the images are created inside the browser - you can still get the `innerHTML` plus the CSS and send it to the server where a headless Chrome can generate the PDF - with much better quality than `html2canvas`.

Comment: Thanks, since it is early development, I would like to use the front end to generate reports as much as possible. Previously, I tried to use pdf synthesis to avoid the problems of too long and too large pages, but it didn't work, because canvas was also used to merge pdf. Temporarily decided to adapt the method of exporting pdf to the browser. In order to avoid the image being truncated, we also needed to calculate the height of elements, insert blank elements, and avoid the content in the truncated position. html2canvas will continue to be used to export

Comment: You might try to use `transform: scale(...)` to make the image (DOM) much smaller during `html2canvas`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using scale will cause the page to blur. Subsequent new requirements added page numbers and other content, using a new way to do it. The background uses the template to generate pdf, and the web side transmits the picture. This meets the requirements for the time being, but it needs to be optimized later.